# serializer_action_class not working in modelviewset in DRF

Tags: django, api, url, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make serializer class dynamic, but its not working. I have a default serializer class where as a dynamic serializer class for different actions. Here it is my modelviewset.

My view:

```
class ClassView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Class.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClassSerializer
    serializer_action_classes = {
        'put': AddStudentstoClassSerializer,
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):

        """
            returns a serializer class based on the http method
        """
        try:
            return self.serializer_action_classes[self.action]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            print("iam ClassSerializer")
            return super(ClassView, self).get_serializer_class()
```

My function inside the same modelviewset above

```
    @action(detail=True, methods=['put'])
    def add_remove_students(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      ................
```

MY url is as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("class/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/",views.ClassView.as_view({"put": "add_remove_students"}),
    ),
]
```

Here in the above code snippet, I try to get AddStudentstoClassSerializer inside the add_remove_students function but it is not working. As we can see the  print("iam ClassSerializer") code is working, however what i wanted or AddStudentstoClassSerializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your `serializer_action_classes` dictionary should look like this:

```
serializer_action_classes = {
    'add_remove_students': AddStudentstoClassSerializer,
}
```

because `self.action` return name of the action, not the method name. What you mean to use is `self.request.method` attribute which shoud return `PUT` in this case..

But there's better way to achieve your goal:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['put'], serializer_class=AddStudentstoClassSerializer)
    def add_remove_students(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

`action` decorators can ovveride used serializer_class by themselves.

Comment: hello monio, thanks for the answer, ie if i use  `serializer_action_classes = {
    'add_remove_students': AddStudentstoClassSerializer,` i dont need to use @action decorator before function??
}

Comment: I guess You need to use it anyway. @action decorator defines detailed urls/actions and without it, this function should be useless. But you can try it... you should register views by DRF router anyway.

Comment: yes it worked even if i removed the decorator, thanks